# JQuery Event not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

My JQuery Script is not firing at all in Internet Explorer (version 11, although it should function on all versions). This code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but when I attempt to run it in FireFox, the second alert "Testing2" does not appear.  
I have already put IE into Edge mode using the following Meta tag, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`.

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
 $(function(){
    alert("Testing1");
    $(document).change(function(){
        alert("Testing2");
        if (window.runConditionalShow) {
            return runConditionalShow();
        }
    });

});
```

The event I am trying to monitor contains the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="property(ApplicationTestform1_date3)" value="05/05/2015" size="10" maxlength="10" id="dateApplicationTestform1_date3" onkeyup="javascript:return mask(this.value,this,'2,5','/',event);">
```

Comment: `onchange` is designed to be fired on input, select and textarea elements. Not to monitor changes to the document. What kind of change do you want to monitor?

Comment: I am monitoring a change to an input element. I have posted the code above.

Comment: You are monitoring changes to `document`. That's not an input element.

Comment: Okay, why does it work on Chrome though?

Comment: I don't know, but probably luck. do a `console.log(event.target)` inside that function to see which element fired it.

Comment: Okay, sorry I took so long to respond, I had to read up on console.log, I ended up getting multiple error messages from tinyMCE (the editor ) which is also on my form page. That is the only thing that appeared on the console

Comment: Next time you have an issue with IE, please specify the version of it. "Edge" is a mode available in many IE versions (and there's also the Edge browser).

Comment: @JeffNoel I added the version. The reason I initially did not add version is because I desire an edit to make it function with any Internet Explorer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `document` to `#dateApplicationTestform1_date3`. It will point to the correct element and fire on change. Reminder it will only do that when the element loses focus.

```js
 $(function(){
    alert("Testing1");
    $("#dateApplicationTestform1_date3").change(function(){
        alert("Testing2");
        if (window.runConditionalShow) {
            return runConditionalShow();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="property(ApplicationTestform1_date3)" value="05/05/2015" size="10" maxlength="10" id="dateApplicationTestform1_date3" >
```

Comment: You are already running an keyup event. But if you want that you should use the input event instead.

Comment: I initially wanted the event to fire on keyup, however it is only working after you edit another field @Mouser

Comment: I was able to get it working using keyup. Thanks @Mouser

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with the input event handler suggested by @Mouser.
On the side note you could try delegating the event.

Also, why I would almost always suggest the event delegation is because in case the input (or any other element) is dynamically added, with event delegation: `$(document).on('event', 'selector'...` you will be able to track the event on that element, otherwise the newly added element will be invisible to the already initiated javascript.

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('input', '#dateApplicationTestform1_date3', function () {
        alert('test');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="property(ApplicationTestform1_date3)" value="05/05/2015" size="10" maxlength="10" id="dateApplicationTestform1_date3" >
```